# mysql_query equivalent to mongoDB

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, benchmarking, nosql

I'm trying to write a `php benchmark` in order to compare some RDBMS, NewSQL and NoSQL.
This script just execute queries and measure the execution time.

For mysql-like, I simply use:

```
$start = microtime(true);
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
$end = microtime(true);
```

I did not fetch data for my benchmark.

But with mongodb-php, function `find()` return a `cursor`

```
$start = microtime(true);
$collection = $this->_db->selectCollection($collection);
$cursor = $collection->find($query);
$end = microtime(true);
```

Does `$cursor` and `$result` are **equivalent (time/data cost)?** Cursor does not load data, I have to iterate cursor in order to load data.. That why time to execute query between MySQL and mongoDB are so different or just mongoDB rocks ...

I wondering if it would be fairer to change my code to:

```
$start = microtime(true);
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {}
$end = microtime(true);
```

and

```
$start = microtime(true);
$cursor = $collection->find($query);
foreach ($cursor as $doc) {}
$end = microtime(true);
```

And finally, is it true to say that each time you iterate on mongodb cursor data are fetch directly from mongodb server and not from computer memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running ->find() indeed just returns the cursor. The query doesn't executed til you fetch the first result. At that moment, the driver will issue the query. This allows you to modify the cursor with things like ->limit() and ->skip(). So yes, it'd be fairer to iterate over the result set as well.

And yes, iterating over the mongoDb cursor, the data is fetch from the MongoDB server. There are no unbuffered queries such as with MySQL (which allows both). Of course, MongoDB will have this data in memory as well-especially if you do it two times just after each other.

Comment: Ok thanks you'r right. But do you think the way I do is good ? Or there is another solution that I have not thought ? Ex: use MongoDB::execute ?

Comment: Execute is not meant for running queries, just for running some arbitrary javascript. I've never had to use that so far. The best thing for benchmarking would be having a real application, or perhaps doing insert testing.

Comment: Yes, for my example I chose select query.. But my benchmark will execute many different type of query (select, insert, update etc ...) on a pseudo real application. But my problem is just about select because mongodb use cursor.